# How to choose from one of two drop down menu insert into the same column of database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have created a category drop down menu and sub category drop down menu. The sub category drop down menu depends on the category drop down menu.
If the user choose Clothing in category menu, then subcategory display shirt,pants and hats.If the user choose Accessories in category menu, then subcategory display shoe,ring and bracet.

I have create mysql query but the problem is if I select Clothing and shirt, the subcategory will not be inserted because the query run the subcategory for Accessories.If I choose Accessories and subcategory,there will be no problem.

How do I resolve this problem so that subcategory for Clothing can be inserted into the database?

*html*

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="Clothing">
        <tr>
          <td align="right">Subcategory</td>
            <td>
              <select name="subcategory[]" id="subcategory[]">
              <option value="">-Select-</option>
              <option value="Hats">Hats</option>
              <option value="Pants">Pants</option>
              <option value="Shirts">Shirts</option>
              </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
      </div>
      <div class="Accessories">
        <tr>
          <td align="right">Subcategory</td>
            <td>
              <select name="subcategory[]" id="subcategory[]">
              <option value="">-Select-</option>
              <option value="Shoe">Shoe</option>
              <option value="Ring">Ring</option>
              <option value="Bracet">Bracet</option>
              </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
      </div>
  </div>
```

*php*

```
 <?php 
    if (isset($_POST['product_name'])) {

    $pid = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['thisID']);
  $product_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['product_name']);
    $price = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['price']);
    $category = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['category']);
    $details = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['details']);
  $quantity = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['quantity']);
     foreach ($_POST['subcategories'] as $subcategory)
      { if($subcategory != '') 
        { $selected_subcategory = mysql_real_escape_string($subcategory); } 
      } 
    // See if that product name is an identical match to another product in the system
    $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE products SET product_name='$product_name', price='$price', details='$details', category='$category', subcategory='$selected_subcategory',vendor='$vendor', quantity='$quantity' WHERE id='$pid'");
    if ($_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'] != "") {
        // Place image in the folder 
        $newname = "$pid.jpg";
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'], "../inventory_images/$newname");
    }
    header("location: vendor_inventory_list.php"); 
    exit();
}
    ?>
```

*javascript*

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#category').bind('change', function() {
        var elements = $('div.container').children().hide(); // hide all the elements
        var value = $(this).val();

        if (value.length) { // if somethings' selected
            elements.filter('.' + value).show(); // show the ones we want
        }
    }).trigger('change');
  });

enter code here
```

Comment: first change the names put like this `name="subcategory1" id="subcategory1"` to any of one

Comment: then,how to add to into the database in the $subcategory?

Comment: which values is this? `$_POST['category']` ?

Comment: You are using same id="subcategory" for both the select subcategories, use different for each

Comment: yeah,then how i would like to add into the same column of database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using hide() in jquery doesn't remove the element. It just hides. 
What actually happening is that both the drop down menus of subcategories are there. And the values are passed. 
Since subcategories for accessories are the last one, it's values is getting through the simple $_POST. 
Either use AJAX, or change the name of subcategory drop downs to subcategory[] and try to get all subcategory select values using

```
 foreach ($_POST['subcategories'] as $subcategory)
 {
    if($subcategory != '')
    {
       $selected_subcategory = $subcategory;
    }
 }
```

Comment: i've to add this code in the php part? before mysql coding is it

Comment: yes. And then insert $selected_subcategory to the table.

Comment: So i dont have to define $subcategory =mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['subcategory']. Just update the table subcategory='$selected_subcategory'

Comment: Then use this code

foreach ($_POST['subcategories'] as $subcategory)
 {
    if($subcategory != '')
    {
       $selected_subcategory = mysql_real_escape_string($subcategory);
    }
 }